# update statement with image

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page with form for updating records and image I don’t know what is wrong with the update statement ,,, the values of fields are taken and I can see them on url through the GET method ... But when I run the page and update record information is not changing and nothing appear on the page ,,, since none of fields r taking the update I think my update statement having problem ,,,here is the code:

```
<?php

    // Connect to the database
    require("includes/conn.php");
    // Script Variables

    $target_dir = 'images/';

    $file_given = false;
    $inputs_given = false;
    $id_given = false;

    if(isset($_POST['serialid']) && $_POST['serialid'] != "")
    {
        $serialid = $_POST['serialid'];
        $id_given = true;
    }


        // You only need to catch input from a create or modify action, so start by checking for ALL the REQUIRED inputs
        if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != "" && isset($_POST['description']) && $_POST['description'] != "" && isset($_POST['price']) && $_POST['price'] != "")
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $paragraph = $_POST['description'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];

            if(isset($_POST['picture']) && $_POST['picture'] != "")
            {
                $picture = basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
                $file_given = true; 
            } 

            // Just some verification (not really much, but you can write your own functions and slot them in
            $name_safe = true;
            $description_safe = true;
            $price_safe = true;
            $picture_safe = false;


            if($_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/png" || $_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/bmp")
                $picture_safe = true;

            if($name_safe && $description_safe && $price_safe && $picture_safe)
                $inputs_given = true;
        }

        if($id_given && $inputs_given)
        {
            // Search for the record and see if it exists
            $get_record = mysql_query("SELECT serial, picture FROM products WHERE serial='$serialid'");
            $record_exists = mysql_num_rows($get_record);

            if($record_exists == 1)
            {
                if($file_given)
                {
                    $update_image = ", picture='$picture'";

                    // Now we need to remove the old image from the file system and upload our new one in it's place

                    $previous_image = mysql_result($get_record,'0','picture');
                    unlink($target_dir . $previous_image);

                    //Now that the previous image has been removed, we need to upload our new image
                    $new_image = $target_dir . $picture ;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $new_image);
                }
                else
                    $update_image = "";

                if(mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name='$name', description='$description', price='$price', " . $update_image . " WHERE serial='$serialid'"))
                    $action_output = "Record successfully modified.";
                else
                    $action_output = "Record modification unsuccessful.";
            }
            else
                $action_output = "The record id you specified does not exist.";
        }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Manage Records</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo $action_output; ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    // Disconnect from the database
?>
```

Here is the url when I click the modify

```
http://localhost/Shopping/update.php?name=View+Sonic+LCD&description=LCD&price=250&picture=C%3A%5CDocuments+and+Settings%5Ce2565%5CMy+Documents%5CTwasul%5Ctlogo%5Cicon%5Cpic1.jpg&serialid=1
```

My Modify Form is this

```
<?php

    // Connect to the database
    require("includes/conn.php");
    $id_given = false;
    if(isset($_POST['serialid']) && $_POST['serialid'] != "")
    {
        $serialid = $_POST['serialid'];
        $id_given = true;
    }

    if($id_given)
    {
        $get_record = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial='$serialid'");
        $record = mysql_fetch_array($get_record);

        $output = '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="update.php?serialid=' . $record['serialid'] . '&action=modify">

                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input name="name" type="text"  value="' . $record['name'] . '"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Description :</td>
                    <td><textarea name="description" cols="45" rows="5">' . $record['description'] . '</textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Price:</td>
                    <td><input name="price" type="text"  value="' . $record['price'] . '"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><img height="50" width="50" src="../images/' . $record['picture'] . '"/><br/>' . $record['picture'] . '</td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                    <td>Modify Image:</td>
                    <td><input name="picture" type="file" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Modify Record"/>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

</form>';

    }
    else
        $output = 'No record id was specified.';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Modify Record</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    // Disconnect from the database
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have an extra comma in this line, before the `WHERE`  :

```
if(mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name='$name', description='$description', price='$price', " . $update_image . " WHERE serial='$serialid'"))
```

The correct syntax is  :

```
if(mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name='$name', description='$description', price='$price' " . $update_image . " WHERE serial='$serialid'"))
```

Then, you said

> I can see them on url through the GET method

But in your script you are using `$_POST` variable to get values, use `$_GET` instead or change the method of your form to `post`. 
If you want to upload a picture you have to use `post` method, the file will be available in the `$_FILES` variable.
In your example, you pass parameters by URL so, with the `get` method, and the "picture" is just the path to the picture in your PC, and it's not uploaded on the server. 

**EDIT :** 

Add `"<input type='hidden' name='serialid' value='".$record['serialid']."' />"` AND `"<input type='hidden' name='action' value='modify' />"` in your form instead of add this parameters to the action url of it, and it should work

Comment: I correct that line but still same nothing happened :( ,, pz look at the url in my post I just added it might help

Comment: Take a look to my edit, you're using `$_POST` variable but you're processing a `GET` reques.

Comment: I change it all to $_Post but same nothing change it didnt work

Comment: @user1084949 Let them to `$_POST` but I think your HTML form use the `get` method, change it.

Comment: I changed the form to POST also and nothing change

Comment: @user1084949 Could you post your HTML form ?

Comment: @user1084949 You should insert `<input type='hidden' />` instead of adding parameters to the action form, read my edit.

Comment: I did that before but no change ,,, for hours Im trying to find what is the prolem but Im not finding I really wish it get solved

Answer (score 0):

you have added comma in  `$update_image = ", picture='$picture'";` as well as in

if(mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name='$name', description='$description', price='$price'`,` " . $update_image . " WHERE serial='$serialid'"))

either remove the comma in `$update_image = " picture='$picture'";` or remove in this

`if(mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name='$name', description='$description', price='$price' " . $update_image . " WHERE serial='$serialid'"))'`

Comment: @user1084949 Try this `mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name='$name', description='$description', price='$price' " . $update_image . " WHERE serial='$serialid'") or die(mysql_error());  `

Comment: I tried that as well still nothing changing empty page shown and record r not update it :(

Comment: just `echo "UPDATE products SET name='$name', description='$description', price='$price' " . $update_image . " WHERE serial='$serialid'"` before the query and check whether you are getting all values correctly.And manually run the query in your phpmyadmin

Comment: And try to use $_POST instead of $_GET its not safe to use $_GET. Since the values are visible through the url

Comment: I changed it all to $_POST and no change can u please check my html form on main post